# Is SPA silently obtain Access-Token from Authorization Server for user with updated claims/roles

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-page-application, auth0, openid-connect

Is the protocol for silently obtaining `Access-Token` in `SPA` while a user session in the `Authorization Server (Auth0)` is still active - Triggers a call to get updated user claims/roles from whichever social connection/database the user authenticated with?

If not, how should I update the silently re-obtained `Access-Token` from the `Authorization Server` with the accurate claims/roles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can supply `prompt=none` as a parameter in an authorization request sent a hidden iframe which will result in a new `id_token` sent back in the authorization response if the SSO session at the Provider is still valid.

Comment: How do the claims get updated? Does the authorization server call the IdP again to get the new values?

Comment: the SPA gets a new authorization code that it can use to call the OP to get a new id_token